# how to insert created date and update date in all the insertion and update requests in JSONB column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have created a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    json_data jsonb
);
```

So in all the insert request I have to insert a created_at time and in all the update request I have to insert the last_update_time to the json data. I am not sure how we can done similar to relational database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a created\_date and updated\_date in JSON object in JSONB column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644090/how-to-insert-a-created-date-and-updated-date-in-json-object-in-jsonb-column-in)

Comment: I have seen that question, the answer states how to concatenate two jsons but I want to know how we can insert updated_date dynamically because cocat does not work in changing the updated_date for the row which has already been updated.

Comment: build env in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ - I will show you how to do it

Comment: here is what I have tried but failed:                                           https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjz6eA2576v5P7vLo1TyEA/1

Comment: uff... 1. so your version is 9.3 as in ticket, or 9.5 as in fiddle?.. 2. `select '192.168.192.16s'::inet;` will raise exception itself - no need in regexp UDF function. 3. o `last_update_time` in your code, 4. you don't need two triggers in fiddle example - just `before insert or update` should do the thing. please refactor your code sample, so it would demonstrate ONE problem and reconcile with this post :)

Comment: Sorry My version is 10.3 but there is no selection for 10.3 in fiddle. The problem with having the last_update_time in the same trigger is that it updates the time only for the first update and any other update query is not updating the timestamp - This might be because it is concatenating the string with same key due to which json just shows only first key value and ignores the other one.

Comment: how is that? I see `for each row` in your trigger - not for statement, thus the trigger fires for each updated row, not for "first"... also - I dont understand the case - your update works fine, but does not work s part of trigger? please simplify the question - make it one clear question, short, replicable case please